how can I compare unmodified and mofidied entity values in a custom repository save method
I want to prepare a custom jparepository save method. In this method I want to compare unmodified and  modified entity field values and then update the modified entity based on the comparison.
When I change the blockReason field's value, In the saveWithCheck method I always read the modified value so that I can't detect the change that I made previously.
What is the reason that I'm always reading modified value in the line. I expect to read unmodified database entity.
Thanks in advance
existingUserStatus = entityManager.find(UserStatus.class, userStatus.getId());

@Repository
@Slf4j
public class CustomUserStatusRepositoryImpl implements CustomUserStatusRepository {
  @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public UserStatus saveWithCheck(UserStatus userStatus) {
    UserStatus existingUserStatus;

    if (nonNull(userStatus.getId())) {
      log.error("id not null");
      existingUserStatus = entityManager.find(UserStatus.class, userStatus.getId());
      if (nonNull(existingUserStatus)) {
        UserBlockReasonType previousBlockReason = existingUserStatus.getBlockReason();
        log.error("Previous block reason: {}", previousBlockReason.name());

        UserBlockReasonType newBlockReason = userStatus.getBlockReason();
        log.error("New block reason: {}", newBlockReason.name());

        if (newBlockReason.equals(UserBlockReasonType.NON)
            && !previousBlockReason.equals(newBlockReason)) {
          log.error("setting block reason non set at");
          userStatus.setBlockReasonNonSetAt(Instant.now());
        }
      }
    }

    if (isNull(userStatus.getId())) {
      log.error("persisting user status");
      if (userStatus.getBlockReason().equals(UserBlockReasonType.NON)) {
        log.error("setting block reason non set at");
        userStatus.setBlockReasonNonSetAt(Instant.now());
      }
      entityManager.persist(userStatus);
    } else {
      log.error("merge user status");
      userStatus = entityManager.merge(userStatus);
    }
    return userStatus;
  }
}

this is th rest of code
@Repository
public interface UserStatusRepository
    extends JpaRepository<UserStatus, Long>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<UserStatus>,
        CustomUserStatusRepository {

  Optional<UserStatus> findByUserId(Long userId);
}


public interface CustomUserStatusRepository {
  UserStatus saveWithCheck(UserStatus userStatus);
}

